# Java Email API emails not being sent properly

Tags: java, email

I am using the Java email API for an email function. It does not appear to be working, since no emails are getting delivered. I do not get any exceptions in my code (so it seems to connect to the smtp properly), and when I debug it, it seems to go fine. So I am wondering if there's something else that's amiss with my code? Here it is, with relevant imports as well. There's also a  "createBody()" method in the class, but it only fills the message with information so I figured that's not of interest.

```
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;



public class Mail {

    public Mail() {
    }

    static public boolean sendHtml(Commission commission, String mailServer, InternetAddress fromAddress, InternetAddress ccAddress, String subject, String header) throws Exception {

        try {
            String body = createBody(commission);
            InternetAddress toAddress = new InternetAddress(commission.getForm().getActiveReceiver().getEmail());

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", mailServer);
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

            //Instantiate a message holder
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset='iso-8859-1'");

            //From
            msg.setFrom(fromAddress);

            //To
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);

            //CC
            if (ccAddress != null)
                msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, ccAddress);

            //Subject
            if (!subject.equals(""))
                msg.setSubject(subject);

            //Date
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());

            //Begin
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            sb.append("<html>\n");
            sb.append("<head>\n");
            sb.append("<title>\n");
            sb.append("</title>\n");
            sb.append("<style type=\"text/css\">\n");
            sb.append("*{font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 11px; font-weight: normal; color: #51514F;}\n");
            sb.append("body{background-color: #FEF8EA;}\n");
            sb.append("tr.odd {background-color: #F3F3F3;border: 1px #F3F3F3 solid;}\n");
            sb.append("tr.even {background-color: #FFFFFF;border: 1px #FFFFFF solid;}\n");
            sb.append("th {font-weight: bold; background-color:#F3F3F3; border-bottom: 1px solid #E2D6BC;}\n");
            sb.append("p.header {font-weight: bold;}\n");
            sb.append("table {border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid #E2D6BC;}\n");
            sb.append("td.center {text-align:center;}\n");
            sb.append("</style>\n");
            sb.append("</head>\n");
            sb.append("<body>\n");

            //Header
            if (!header.equals(""))
                sb.append("<h1>"+header+"</h1>");

            //Body
            if (!body.equals("")) 
                sb.append(body);

            //End
            sb.append("</body>\n");
            sb.append("</htmnl>\n");

            msg.setContent(sb.toString(), "text/html");
            System.out.println("About to connect");
            //Connect
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect();


            //Sending the mail
    transport.sendMessage(msg,msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));

            //Sending the CC mail
            if (ccAddress != null)
        transport.sendMessage(msg,msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC));

            //Close
            transport.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Haven't used this framework lately, but you should check a few things... 1. Are you allowed to use the server without authentication? 2. Your try/catch block do nothing, before rethrowing the exception, at least put a line with e.printStackTrace(), just in case it's not in the calling method. 3. Have you tested the mail server from a simple telnet client (telnet mailserver 25), then just use the SMTP commands. 4. Have you checked if the connection really establishes, and if the server is getting any messages?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. It may help you.

```
 Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(System.getProperties());    
 Transport transport 
      = new SMTPTransport(mailSession,new URLName("mail.your-server.com"));    
 transport.connect("mail.your-server.com",portNumber,userName,userPassword);
```

Exmaple:

```
 Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(System.getProperties());
 Transport transport 
     = new SMTPTransport(mailSession,new URLName("mail.prabhakar.com"));
 transport.connect("mail.prabhakar.com",25,"prabhakar","******");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on smtp debug and see what's happening at `SMTP` level:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host","<MAILHOST>");
props.put("mail.debug", true);
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
```